# epsilon delta limit proof verification of $\lim_{x\to2}{\frac{x-1}{x^2-1}} = \frac{1}{3} $.

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

I just want to verify the preliminary work of my epsilon delta proof for this one.

> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}{\frac{x-1}{x^2-1}} = \frac{1}{3} $$

$\underline{\text{prelimnary work}}$

$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0$ $s.t.$ 
$|x-2|<\delta\Rightarrow \left|\frac{x-1}{x^2-1}-\frac{1}{3}\right|<\epsilon$

we know
$$\left|\frac{x-1}{x^2-1}-\frac{1}{3}\right| = 
\left|\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{3(x-1)(x+1)}\right|$$

now we take $x>1$ to cancel $x-1$; 
we pick $\delta<a$ such that $2-a>1$ i.e. $0<a<1$; therefore $\delta< 0.5$ will do. Thus, $\delta<0.5$ therefore $|x-2|<\delta<0.5$
$$1.5<x<2.5$$

now we have
$$\left|\frac{(x-1)(x-2)}{3(x-1)(x+1)}\right| = \left|\frac{(x-2)}{3(x+1)}\right|<|x-2|<\epsilon $$
hence $\delta = \min(0.5, \epsilon)$

$\underline{\text{proof}}$

take $\delta = 0.5$ or $\delta = \epsilon ...$

is there anything wrong with my proof? Crtisim is highly appreciated

Comment: Showing the preliminary work and just a start of the proof doesn't count as showing the proof.

Comment: @md2perpe i just want to verify whether the preliminary work is correct first :)

Comment: @md2perpe i've edited the quesiton just now

Comment: We don't need $x > 1$ to cancel $x-1.$ We only need $x \neq 1.$

Comment: The proof looks okay to me. I would make some changes in the exposition, but in essence it's correct.

Comment: @md2perpe yeah that's why $x>1$ then $x\neq1$

Comment: @ErikHambardzumyan. But you write "now we must make $x>1$ to cancel $x−1$" which is not true. If you instead write "now we take $x>1$ to cancel $x-1$" then it would be clearer.

Comment: @md2perpe yeah in terms of modal verbs; we do not have to make it >1, since >1 is one of the options; I agree. Will change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is very good. You have explained every step very clearly.

Note that at $$\left|\frac{(x-2)}{3(x+1)}\right|<|x-2|<\epsilon$$

You could have done a little bit better by considering $3(x+1)>7.5$

Thus we could have said  $$\left|\frac{(x-2)}{3(x+1)}\right|<|x-2|/{7.5}<\epsilon$$ Which makes your $\delta = \min(0.5,7.5\epsilon)$